# S3 Flume HDFS SINK Compression

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, flume-ng

I am trying to write the flume events in Amaozn S3.The events written in S3 is in compressed format. My Flume configuration is given below. I am facing a data loss. Based on the configuration given below, if I publish 20000 events, I receive only 1000 events and all other data is lost. But When I disable the rollcount, rollSize and rollInterval configurations, all the events are received but there are 2000 small files created. Is there any wrong in my configuration settings? Should I add any other configurations?

```
injector.sinks.s3_3store.type = hdfs
injector.sinks.s3_3store.channel = disk_backed4
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.codeC = gzip
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.serializer = TEXT
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.path = s3n://CID:SecretKey@bucketName/dth=%Y-%m-%d-%H
injector.sinks.s3_1store.hdfs.filePrefix = events-%{receiver}
# Roll when files reach 256M or after 10m, whichever comes first
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.rollCount = 0
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.idleTimeout = 600
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.rollSize = 268435456
#injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.rollInterval = 3600
# Flush data to buckets every 1k events
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters: if you disable your setting for rollCount, rollSize and so on, flume will revert to defaults, hence the small files you receive, those are the default.

The relevant aspect is this:

```
injector.sinks.s3_3store.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
```

it basically tells your sink to collect 10.000 events before flushing. If you reduce that amount, you'll get smaller files too, because S3 in contrast to regular HDFS doesn't support file appends. Once you flush, the files will be closed and a new file will be created.

Try to determine which amount of events your sink will receive within a short time frame of a couple of minutes or so and set that value as you batch size.